# Undefined property: PDO::$connect_error

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to use `$dbc->connect_error` to check if any error occurs while trying to connect to my databease. I always get an error page saying:

> Notice: Undefined property: PDO::$connect_error in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\add_products_processing.php on line 7

I am using Windows7 with XAMPP v3.2.2. The full code is shown below. I am sure that the username and the password are correct. Any advice?

```
<?php

$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=technoglance';
$username = 'root';
$password = 'password';
$dbc = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
if ($dbc->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $dbc->connect_error);
}

$main_class =filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'main_class');
$brand =filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'brand');
$model =filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'model');
$description =filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'description');
$quantity =filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'quantity');
$adding_date =filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'adding_date');
$sell_price =filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'sell_price');
$buying_price =filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'buying_price');

if(!empty($main_class)){
             try{
            $query = "INSERT INTO products (main_class, brand, model, description, quantity, adding_date, sell_price, buying_price ) VALUES ('$main_class', '$brand', '$model', '$description', '$quantity', now(),'$sell_price', '$buying_price' );";
             // set the PDO error mode to exception
            $dbc->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $dbc->exec($query);
             echo "Thank you. The record has been sent successfully.<br><br>";

            }
            catch(PDOException $e){
                echo $query . "<br>" . $e->getMessage()."<br><br>";

            }
}
else{
    echo '<h1>Please use the contact form or don\'t leave an empty field!</h1>';
}

?>
```

Comment: What makes you think that `PDO::$connect_error` should exist? It is mentioned nowhere in the documentation.

Comment: Besides, your code is prone to SQL injection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what your code should be

```
<?php

$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=technoglance;charset=utf8';
$username = 'root';
$password = 'password';
$dbc = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
$dbc->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// filtering omitted

if(!empty($main_class)){
    $query = "INSERT INTO products (main_class, brand, model, description, quantity, adding_date, sell_price, buying_price ) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);";
    $data = [$main_class,$brand,$model,$description,$quantity,$adding_date,$sell_price,$buying_price];
    $dbc->prepare($query)->execute($data);
    echo "Thank you. The record has been sent successfully.<br><br>";}
else{
    echo '<h1>Please use the contact form or don\'t leave an empty field!</h1>';
}
```

[PDO will report it's errors already, without any extra code required](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#errors).
and you should be using prepared statements

Answer (score 2):

If we have a look at the [PDO manual](http://php.net/pdo) and look up for the [PDO class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) there is no `connect_error` property anywhere. But if we check [mysqli manual](http://php.net/mysqli)  we see it [right there](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-error.php). You have to choose a database library and stick to it, they cannot be mixed.

I always recommend to configure PDO to [throw exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) as you already do (although connection errors in particular will always through an exception no matter your settings) and not care to catch them unless you want to do something specific with them.

Answer (score 0):

There is no connect_error. You should use exception:

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Or if you do not want exception you can try [errorCode](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorcode.php) and [errorInfo](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php)

Comment: Or, BTW, simply *not catch the exception*. Simpler code, better error reporting, same result.