# How to get laravel DB connection to php connection?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5

I need to receive laravel DB connection to variable to make concrete pure SQL php demands on a database. Desired code:

```
<?php 
// this is not working
$conn = DB::connection();

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

Desired result: "Connected successully"

I need it because I have very complex SQL demands that I need to put in one query, not using laravel query syntax (I believe it is better approach, but I have complex queries and need to use pure query text to execute, not laravel "->" syntax)

I need to get laravel DB connection to not always often establish second php connection like with PDO or writing down DB credentials. If PDO connection to DBS from laravel exists, it could be useful to obtain to php for me too.

```
DB::connection()->name
```

returns a name of DB, but thats no connection :/

I was looking for it but nowhere found solution for that, could someone help me find correct answer please? (maybe it is not important, but I use mysql)

Comment: You can use `\DB::statement('raw query here');`.

Comment: But how to obtain a result (or result Set) from this statement? or it is even possible to get that connection as I asked for? but thanks for your contribution, I will look closer on that statement syntax .. I found another good thing, but no answer on my question: $results = DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE some_col = '$someVariable'") );

Comment: Did you try to read the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/database#running-queries ?

Comment: Dunno if this could be useful: `DB::connection()->getPdo()`

Comment: of course that I read that documentation Alex Blex... my main question is how to get connection from laravel to php...

Comment: @dparoli ... Undefined property: PDO::$connect_error ... this seems not working too..

Comment: for the connect_error see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37432029/undefined-property-pdoconnect-error

Comment: You will not be able to detect the connect error in this way as the facade that will expose the PDO instance will only be available if a connection is successful.

Comment: you do not need to make by your own, Laravel is a framework which provide us a way to connect our project with differet other objects or Files like mysql database file. you need to set your .env file. where you can set database name, user name, password, port no etc...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use raw query in laravel for executing queries as you wish. If you need connection instance anyway you can create a class and implement ConnectionResolverInterface:

```
use Illuminate\Database\ConnectionResolverInterface as Resolver
class connection implements Resolver {

}
```

then you can get connection:

```
$connector = new connection();
$connection = $connector->connection();
```

If you're using your model connection you can get connection this way:

```
$user = new User();
$user->getConnection();
```

Also you can make a new connection by using ConnectionFactory:

```
$connection = new Illuminate\Database\Connector\ConnectionFactory();
```

for more information you can see [laravel API doc](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Database/Connectors.html)

Comment: interesting, but this is creation of new connection instance, can I get somehow existing connection?

Comment: try getDefaultConnection on same interface.

Comment: maybe I don't understand, maybe you can update your answer with code.. but as far as I know about getDefaultConnection, it only returns string name of connection but not concrete connection...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$pdo = $eloquentConnection->getConnection()->getRawPdo();
```

Cheers