# Insert data from a form with required fields

Tags: php

Please i need help with this form i have those problems Please help me
1- When it submit write error but i see in PHPMyAdmin it's added and record in MySql Database
Example:
Error: INSERT INTO clients (name, email, website, comment, gender) VALUES ('', '', '', '', '')

2- When i don't fill and a required field i see the error message but it's added and record in MySql Database
Example
Email is required

my code is below

```
    <?php
    // Database information
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "mymbnwye_mexx";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "";

// Database connection
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully"; 
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }


// Check input 
function checker_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}

// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = $emailErr = $genderErr = $websiteErr = "";
$name = $email = $gender = $comment = $website = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $nameErr = "Name is required";
  } else {
    $name = checker_input($_POST["name"]);
  }

  if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $emailErr = "Email is required";
  } else {
    $email = checker_input($_POST["email"]);
  }

  if (empty($_POST["website"])) {
    $website = "";
  } else {
    $website = checker_input($_POST["website"]);
  }

  if (empty($_POST["comment"])) {
    $comment = "";
  } else {
    $comment = checker_input($_POST["comment"]);
  }

  if (empty($_POST["gender"])) {
    $genderErr = "Gender is required";
  } else {
    $gender = checker_input($_POST["gender"]);
  }



  $sql = "INSERT INTO clients (name, email, website, comment, gender)
VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$website', '$comment', '$gender')";

  if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}




}

?>

<h2>PHP Form Validation Example</h2>
<p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">  
  Name: <input type="text" name="name">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  E-mail: <input type="text" name="email">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  Website: <input type="text" name="website">
  <span class="error"><?php echo $websiteErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  Comment: <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
  <br><br>
  Gender:
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $genderErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
</form>
```

Comment: please use `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` on top of your page and let us know which error is thrown.

Comment: @OldPadawan Notice: Undefined property: PDO::$error in /home/mymbnwye/public_html/me/final/add.php on line 60
Error: INSERT INTO clients (name, email, website, comment, gender) VALUES ('', '', '', '', '')

Comment: You are not checking if errors were found before running the query, so it will save to the database always. I do not understand your first problem. Please clarify.

Comment: Undefined property means there is no such property called `error`. Try using http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php

Comment: found this [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37432029/undefined-property-pdoconnect-error) and it'll be helpful. EDIT: as said in the post and stated by @inarilo -> no such `error`

Comment: try to `var_dump($_POST)` to see all your data after submitting the form

Comment: Your Code Is Work fine ... I try it .. my self ! Data is Inserted !!

Comment: and You Can use HTML 5 Required validation !! other Check isset for all the values using php in if condition !!

Comment: @RïshïKêshKümar : this is not what OP asked for...

Comment: Try wrapping in `try`/`catch` on that. If it fails to insert, you can probably catch the mysql error in the catch and use `$e->getMessage();` like you have for the connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using code that you have mentioned, your sql query will always execute event if there is empty fields because you are writing your query outside of condition.

This code will help solving your problem

```
if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $nameErr = "Name is required";
} else if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $emailErr = "Email is required";
} else if (empty($_POST["gender"])) {
    $genderErr = "Gender is required";
} else {

    $name = checker_input($_POST["name"]);
    $gender = checker_input($_POST["gender"]);
    $comment = empty($_POST["comment"]) ? "" :checker_input($_POST["comment"]);
    $website = empty($_POST["website"]) ? "" :checker_input($_POST["website"]);
    $email = checker_input($_POST["email"]);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO clients (name, email, website, comment, gender)
    VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$website', '$comment', '$gender')";

    if ($conn->query($sql)) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
}
```

Comment: This code is treating valid empty values as errors.

Comment: sorry, my bad @inarilo

Comment: The other error still exists. `$conn->error` will throw an error.

Comment: @Divyank thanks very much but i see this error
Error: INSERT INTO clients (name, email, website, comment, gender) VALUES ('eddy', 'rtr@frg.cc', 'grgr', 'htryhh', 'female')
and i found it's add record to DB

Comment: PDO::query() returns the result set (if any) returned by the statement as a PDOStatement object. so just write `if ($conn->query($sql))` instead of `if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE)`

Comment: and if you are using PDO, then you should use parameterized query

Answer (score 1):

This should work for the PDO Database:

- It won't submit to your database until you complete all the required fields and will also display the required input error messages.
- It won't clear all the fields if you forget to fill in one of the required fields and submit.

I added an If statement to the connection.

```
<?php
 // define variables and set to empty values
   $nameErr = $emailErr = $cityErr = $commentErr = $genderErr = "";
   $name = $email = $city = $comment = $gender = "";

  if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
   if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
     $nameErr = "Please add a name";
  } else {
      $name = validateInput($_POST["name"]);
      // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
      if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]+/",$name)) {$nameErr = "Only letters and white 
      space allowed";} 
    }

  if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $emailErr = "Please add an email";
  } else {
     $email = validateInput($_POST["email"]);
     // check if email is an email format
      if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
      }
    }

 if (empty($_POST["city"])) {
    $cityErr = "Please add your city";
  } else {
    $city = validateInput($_POST["city"]);
    // check if city only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$city)) {
        $cityErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["comment"])) {
    $commentErr = "Please add your comment";
  } else {
    $comment = validateInput($_POST["comment"]);
       // check if comment only contains letters and whitespace
       if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$comment)) {
        $commentErr = 'Only "/", "-", "+", and numbers';  
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["gender"])) {
    $genderErr = "Please pick your gender";
  } else {
    $gender = validateInput($_POST["gender"]);

    }
}

// Validate Form Data 
function validateInput($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
  }


if(!empty($_POST["name"]) && !empty($_POST["email"]) && !empty($_POST["city"]) && !empty($_POST["comment"]) && !empty($_POST["gender"]))
  {
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "";
  $dbname = "myDBPDO";

  try {
      $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
      // set the PDO error mode to exception
      $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
      $sql = "INSERT INTO info (name, email, city, comment, gender)
      VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$city', '$comment', '$gender')";
      // use exec() because no results are returned
      $conn->exec($sql);
      echo "Success! Form Submitted!";
      }
  catch(PDOException $e)
      {
      echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
      }

  $conn = null;
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body> 




<h2>PHP Form</h2>
<p>Doesn't submit until the required fields you want are filled</p>


<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"> 
  <div class="error">
    <p><span>* required field</span></p>
    <div><?php echo $nameErr;?></div>
    <div><?php echo $emailErr;?></div>
    <div><?php echo $cityErr;?></div>
    <div><?php echo $commentErr;?></div>
    <div><?php echo $genderErr;?></div>              
  </div>
    <label for="name">Name:
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
        <span class="error">*</span>
    </label>
    <label for="email">Email:
      <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
        <span class="error">*</span>
    </label>
    <label for="city">city:
      <input type="text" name="city" id="city" placeholder="" value="<?php echo $city;?>">
        <span class="error">*</span>
    </label>
    <label for="comment">comment:
      <input type="text" name="comment" id="comment" value="<?php echo $comment;?>">
        <span class="error">*</span>
    </label>
    <label for="gender">Gender:<br>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="female") echo "checked";?> value="female">Female
      <input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="male") echo "checked";?> value="male">Male
      <input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="other") echo "checked";?> value="other">Other  
        <span class="error">*</span>
    </label>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Use this if you want to redirect it to another page so it won't send the form again to your PDO database if they refresh it.

- It won't submit to your database and will stay on the HOME.PHP page until you complete all the required fields and will also display the required input error messages while on HOME.PHP page.
- It won't clear all the fields if you forget to fill in one of the required fields and submit.

Added a "header("Location: welcome.php");" after "$conn->exec($sql);"

**HOME.PHP**

```
<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = $emailErr = $cityErr = $commentErr = $genderErr = "";
$name = $email = $city = $comment = $gender = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $nameErr = "Please add a name";
  } else {
    $name = validateInput($_POST["name"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]+/",$name)) {$nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";} 
    }

  if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $emailErr = "Please add an email";
  } else {
    $email = validateInput($_POST["email"]);
    // check if email is an email format
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["city"])) {
    $cityErr = "Please add your city";
  } else {
    $city = validateInput($_POST["city"]);
    // check if city only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$city)) {
        $cityErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["comment"])) {
    $commentErr = "Please add your comment";
  } else {
    $comment = validateInput($_POST["comment"]);
       // check if comment only contains letters and whitespace
       if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$comment)) {
        $commentErr = 'Only "/", "-", "+", and numbers';  
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["gender"])) {
    $genderErr = "Please pick your gender";
  } else {
    $gender = validateInput($_POST["gender"]);

    }
}

// Validate Form Data 
function validateInput($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
  }


if(!empty($_POST["name"]) && !empty($_POST["email"]) && !empty($_POST["city"]) && !empty($_POST["comment"]) && !empty($_POST["gender"]))
  {
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "";
  $dbname = "myDBPDO";

  try {
      $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
      // set the PDO error mode to exception
      $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
      $sql = "INSERT INTO info (name, email, city, comment, gender)
      VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$city', '$comment', '$gender')";
      // use exec() because no results are returned
      $conn->exec($sql);
      header("Location: welcome.php");
      }
  catch(PDOException $e)
      {
      echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
      }

  $conn = null;
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body> 




<h2>PHP Form</h2>
<p>Doesn't submit until the required fields you want are filled</p>


<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"> 
  <div class="error">
    <p><span>* required field</span></p>
    <div><?php echo $nameErr;?></div>
    <div><?php echo $emailErr;?></div>
    <div><?php echo $cityErr;?></div>
    <div><?php echo $commentErr;?></div>
    <div><?php echo $genderErr;?></div>              
  </div>
    <label for="name">Name:
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
        <span class="error">*</span>
    </label>
    <label for="email">Email:
      <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
        <span class="error">*</span>
    </label>
    <label for="city">city:
      <input type="text" name="city" id="city" placeholder="" value="<?php echo $city;?>"> 
      <span class="error">*</span>
    </label>
    <label for="comment">comment:
      <input type="text" name="comment" id="comment" value="<?php echo $comment;?>">
      <span class="error">*</span>
    </label>
    <label for="gender">Gender:<br>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="female") echo "checked";?> value="female">Female
      <input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="male") echo "checked";?> value="male">Male
      <input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="other") echo "checked";?> value="other">Other  
        <span class="error">*</span>
    </label>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**WELCOME.PHP**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=\, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Success! Form Submitted!</h1>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't stop the query being executed if there are missing values. Try something like this instead:

```
function ValuesCompleted()
{
    $values = Array('name', 'email', 'gender');

    foreach($values as $index)
    {
        if(empty($_POST[$index]))
        {
            return "{$index} not supplied";
        }
    }

    return true;
}

if(isset($_POST) && ValuesCompleted() === true)
{
    try
    {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

        $statement = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO clients (name, email, website, comment, gender)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

        $statement->execute(Array($_POST['name'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['website'], $_POST['comment'], $_POST['gender']);

        $conn = null;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        // ideally you would print this to a log, not echo it.
        echo($e->getMessage());
    }
}
else
{
    echo ValuesCompleted();
}
```

Comment: That **is** a simple way..... ? If you don't understand any of it then it's up to you to read the documentation or actually state which part you don't understand. The other obviously simple way is to pay someone else to just do it for you...